# Database data convert to '????'

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, arabic

I have a MYSQL database contain Arabic data, when i upload it to my domain , Arabic records converted to question marks like '????' !
i check the variables and it's look like this:

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';

```
Variable_name              Value
character_set_client       utf8
character_set_connection   utf8
character_set_database     utf8
character_set_filesystem   binary
character_set_results      utf8
character_set_server       latin1
character_set_system       utf8
```

Comment: so what is your problem and what do you want to solve?

Comment: :ss 
The data converted from Arabic characters to question marks..as example:
مرحبا
after:
?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the column you are storing the text in is `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to check.  You should have `CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Comment: not just one column ! all arabic data in all tables !